# Ensuring Windows Mobile application is not running - From a desktop app

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a windows mobile 5.0 application (smartphone) that contains a flat data file (CSV), which contains a header row (two doubles), and a list of entries (two doubles, DateTime, and a string).

Occasionally, I need to "sync" the mobile application with a desktop application.  The desktop application should read the CSV from the mobile device, and replace it with a new CSV file, based on the contents of the old one.

This seems pretty easy via RAPI (I'm guessing), but I need to ensure that the mobile application is not running.  Is there a way to do this?

Mutex?  Remote Process Viewer like stuff?  File locking?

Thanks for any help you have

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple file locking mechanism for the file being read/updated.

Either rename the file before use or create a second 'lock' file which you can check for the existence of.

Comment: And if the app crashes and doesn't delete the file?

Comment: Yes, have a time limit for lock files. If the lock is 2 minutes old, but no app should ever hold a lock for more than a minute, ignore the lock.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, the [built-in RAPI Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457105.aspx) don't have anything for checking running processes like the [ToolHelp API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915058.aspx).  With C you could create a set of custom functions in a device library that call the ToolHelp APIs and in turn are called through [CeRapiInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms834931.aspx) (which is a generic catch-all entry point for custom RAPI functions).  Unfortunately there's no simple mechanism to do this in managed code.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought of an easy way.

Every 3 seconds the program is running, update a registry key with the current datetime.

When I want to sync, check the mobile registry, check it again 5 seconds later.  If the values changed, the program is still running.

Comment: This would be a really bad idea. Having the mobile application perform a task with such frequency would affect it's ability to go into low power mode. This would greatly impact battery life.